# Django - Enter a list of value

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

MY MODEL :

```
class Annonce(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    domaines = models.ManyToManyField(Domaine, null=True,related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")
```

My FORM :

```
class annonceForm(forms.ModelForm) :
    class Meta : 
        model = Annonce
        fields = ['title','domaines','presentation']
        widgets = {
            'domaines': forms.Select(attrs={'size': 1}),
            }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(annonceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['domaines'].required = False
    self.fields['domaines'].queryset = Domaine.objects.all().values_list("nom",flat=True)
```

When I want save one Annonce in my form annonceForm, I have this error message :

> " Enter a list of values " below the Select of "domaines"

Comment: Yes, because it's a many to many field. If you don't want that, you should use a different field - maybe a ForeignKey?

Comment: No because, ANNONCE may haves many DOMAINE

Comment: So why are you using a widget that only allows you to set a single one?

Comment: Because in the future, I want add one option for add many forms.Select  on the click ^^

Comment: Removed unnecessary formatting and formatted error message

Answer (score 3):

For a M2M relation you should be using a MultipleChoiceField in your form class respectively it's widget SelectMultiple:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield

Django expects a list of values or an empty list for the M2M relation domaines while your form is sending a single value.
Think about how would a single-select field display more than one value of an existing Annonce, it can't.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.. <3

Answer (score 1):

The domaines being ManyToManyField, the form widget suitable for your needs will be the forms.SelectMultiple

```
category = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=ProductCategory.objects.filter(is_published=True),
    widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'multiple': ''}),)
```